# Disabling input in a Pivot during a transition?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I've got an issue with the Pivot Control on Windows Phone 7. In the application I'm developing, in addition to being able to use the standard swipe left and right to change pivot page the pivot control also auto advances when buttons are pressed by setting the SelectedIndex.

During the transition if the screen is tapped a button press is registered. Until the animation has settled this button press is for the wrong button. (I.e. if the SelectedItem is increasing a tap on the right side of the screen will result in a button on the left side being selected)

The application being implemented is a quiz application. A rewrite to replace the pivot control isn't really feasible at this stage as the app is near complete apart from this one issue, and the Pivot provides all the rest of the functionality required.

So, is there any way to stop input being passed while the animation is in progress?

I've tried setting IsEnabled on the Pivot, but this causes the animation to lose all fluidity - simply flashing to the next item rather than scrolling. Presumably because both these tasks will be running on the UI thread.

Has anyone got any other suggestions for solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the pivot during the changing of the PivotItem to prevent such taps.

Set it to `false` when the pivot is `UnloadingPivotItem` and then enable it on the `LoadedPivotitem` event.

Answer (score 1):

After a short test it appears that the Pivot.LoadedPivotItem event fires after the animation is complete. This means you could use a boolean field to suppress the button event handler while animation is in progress.

When you set the selected index:

```
_suppressEvents = true;
uxPivot.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Then in the LoadedPivotItem event:

```
_suppressEvents = false;
```

And in the Button events:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_suppressEvents)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Little add to the original answer.. you can lock each pivot also just by setting `isLocked = true`

and for the buttons

```
//unlock
SettingsPivot.IsLocked = false;
//navigate
SettingsPivot.SelectedItem = OtherSettings;
//lock new pivot
SettingsPivot.IsLocked = true;
```